# How to stop ng-click event and run it later by another custom directive

Tags: angularjs, events, addeventlistener, angularjs-ng-click

I need to animate each click on a website. So i created a derictive for this. But, not all events works fine, for example if it's `ui-sref` or `ng-click` event that changing state or opening a modal window, animation is can not get in time.

I'm trying to catch click event and run it later. How to stop it, i know, but how tu run it later i dont know, except an `element.triggerHandler('click')` but it calls click event again which i'm stopping.

On ngLick can be a function or condition.
If you’re thinking, I’m trying to get the `$state.go`.

```
.directive('clickEffect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

          if (md.mobile()) {

            element[0].addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();
              evt.stopPropagation();
            }, true);

            var staticClass = element.attr('ce-static-class') || 'cbutton cbutton--effect-jelena';
            var animationClass = element.attr('ce-animation-class') || 'cbutton--click';
            var animationName = element.attr('ce-animation-name') || 'anim-effect-jelena';

            var onAnimationEnd = function(event) {
              if (event.animationName === animationName) {
                element.removeClass(animationClass);
                // element.triggerHandler('click');
              }
            };

            element.addClass(staticClass);

            element.on('mousedown', function () {
              element.addClass(animationClass);
            });

            element.on('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
          }
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<a ng-click="isMobileMenuOpened = {visible: true}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the event, run the click animation function, then emit a new custom event, like: `rootScope.$broadcast(clickAnimationFinished, data).`

Then, in your other custom directives, you just subscribe: `scope.$on('clickAnimationFinished', codeThatWasPreviouslyRunningOnClicks());`

You could improve this further by creating a custom directive and replacing ng-click.

Comment: i'm trying not to use my custom ng-click directive.

Comment: I dont nedd to use broadcast, i know how to call event when i need it. ho can i get event what is placed in ng-click from another directive? ho to get this `codeThatWasPreviouslyRunningOnClicks()` and run it?